# Account Teams limit record access

Tags: community, partner-communities, account-teams

I want to use Account Teams to assign Partners to customer's Accounts/Opps/Cases so they can access the records in Partner Community. I can easily grant them Read or Read/Write to these objects this way, however once they have access I want to limit which records they actually see. I want them to see the full Account page, but then limit what Customer Opps/Cases they see based on a custom lookup field on those objects. The lookup field looks up to the Partner Account.

How can I accomplish this? Right now, if I assign multiple Partners via Account Teams, they can see all of the customer opps/cases but I only want them to see the ones where their Account is in the lookup.

Comment: That's not how Account Teams work. You'll need to come up with an alternative solution, probably involving an Apex Trigger.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Account Teams? I found the way to do it is to do Accounts as Read/Write, and then Opps/Cases as Private and then grant access to the records for Opps/Cases via Sharing Sets